# Steam does not launch on 15.04

Tags: 15.04, steam

Could not find the very same problem elsewhere.

Config is : i5-4590 on ASrock H97M Anniversary, 16GB RAM, GTX 970 from ASUS. Ubuntu 15.04 and drivers Nvidia 352.21.

When start Steam, I got the verify for update popup, then it crashes.

I have the below trace

```
User@PC:~$ steam --verbose
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1433441724)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1433441724)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1433441724)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1433441724)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[0715/184514:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(170)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Installing breakpad exception handler for  appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20150604103540)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1433414140)
[0715/184514:ERROR:nss_util.cc(981)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20150604103540)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1433441724)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1433441724)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1433441724)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1433441724)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1433441724)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1433441724)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1433441724)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1433441724)
FillInMachineIDInfo took a total of 0 milliseconds
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1433441724)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1433441724)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[0715/184515:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(212)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0715/184515:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(212)] Running without renderer sandbox
assert_20150715184512_1.dmp[13739]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20150715184512_1.dmp
/home/User/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 756: 13678 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
[0715/184515:ERROR:sandbox_ipc_linux.cc(431)] sendmsg: Broken pipe
assert_20150715184512_1.dmp[13739]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
assert_20150715184512_1.dmp[13739]: error: HTTP response code said error
assert_20150715184512_1.dmp[13739]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20150715184512_1.dmp'', upload no: ''HTTP response code said error''
User@PC:~$
```

Where should I start?

Comment: Have you attempted `sudo apt-get --purge remove steam && sudo apt-get install steam`?

Comment: in doubt, I just tried that and end up with the very same result.